# Product sorting in magento on the basis of disscount

Tags: magento, admin, magento-1.9

In Product listing page in Magneto I want that the discounted product will be listed last in the list.

Can any one know how to achieve this from Admin side or by Pragmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could **addColumn** in your Product Grid which then you could sort by:

Using a custom module ([see here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643) to create a custom module)

In your custom module's config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YOUR_MODULE>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </YOUR_MODULE>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_grid>YOUR_MODULE_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now in **app/code/local/YOUR/MODULE/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/**. Create file: **Grid.php**:

```
<?php 
class YOUR_MODULE_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('discounted_price', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Discount Price'),
            'align' => 'left',
            'index' => 'discounted_price',
            'type'  => 'price',
            'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
            'width'     => '70',
            'renderer' => 'YOUR_MODULE_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_DiscountPrice' //This is important!
        )); 
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Notice the **renderer** element, this is where we will work out the discounted price. Now in **app/code/local/YOUR/MODULE/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Renderer/**. Create file: **DiscountedPrice.php**:

```
<?php
class YOUR_MODULE_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_DiscountPrice extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
        $storeId = (int) Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()); // Original value should you need it
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($row["entity_id"]);
        $discounted_price =   Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->calcProductPriceRule($product,$product->getPrice());
        return '<span>'.$discounted_price.'</span>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

You should now see custom column in Catalog > Manage Products named "Discounted Price" which you can now sort by! Hope this helps.